# VBA Control of IE - In explicable behavior

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, vba, excel, runtime-error

Bizarre problem.

I am using Excel VBA to control IE and download data from web sites.  Pretty vanilla.

I experience an error that only happens when I am running Windows 8.1 and IE 10.  On a second PC, which is running Windows 7 and IE 8, the code works fine.

Here is the behavior.

I call the following code to open a web page:

```
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With appIE
.navigate sURL 'Where sURL is a valid web address
End With
```

This works fine, and opens a browser. 
Shortly afterwards, I call the following:

```
With appIE
.navigate sURL'a different valid web address
End With
```

An error message pops up at the .navigate line.  The message says:

Run-time Error '-2147024726(800700aa)'
Method 'Navigate' of object 'IEWebBrowser2' Failed

I have looked up this error message and the only thing that I can find is that it may relate to spyware.  But I completely reinstalled the OS and all apps on the system and the same thing happened.

Another very strange phenomenon is that if I put a trace point in-between the above two sections and pause the code, then manually start the code again, everything works fine.  But if, instead of me putting in a trace point I put in a wait loop, I get the same failure.  That is, if I manually pause and then resume the code, the code works, but if I automate a pause and resume, the code does not work.

As you consider this situation, please remember that everything works fine under Windows 7 and IE 8, and everything works fine if I manually pause and restart.

Does any of this make sense?

Comment: You said 'shortly afterwards'. Do you check for `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` on the first `sURL` before navigating to the second one? IE10 has always had issues with Excel VBA, some of which are just completely nuts.

Comment: Yes, I use a Do While appIE.busy lop before continuing.  And I've tried putting gin a long pause as well.

Answer (score 0):

1- **Please Check sURL** (if you check, please check again compiled folder)

2- Delete WebBrowser Control and Add New

Me forget copy original file App.Path + "\error.html" and see this problem.